# How to execute insert query without actually opening the php file and showing a blank page?

Tags: php, html

I have a main form which has a submit button that when pressed it inserts employee data using an insert query, but when I press the submit button in the form it opens a blank page because there is no visible content in the resulting form. How can i get it so that when I press the submit button it just enters the data but remains on the same form and doesn't open a blank page. Is this even possible? Will I have to simply copy the style of index.php into the process.php file? Please help I am new and want to learn.

Here is my code (index.php)

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>


    <form action="process.php" method="post" style="position:relative; top:200px;left:150px">
        First Name: <input type="text" style="position:relative;left:14px"name="firstName"><br>
        Last Name: <input type="text" style="position:relative;left:15px"name="lastName"><br>

        <input type="submit"style="position:relative;left:88px"name="submitButton"  ><br>


    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the resulting php file where the query is executed (process.php)

```
<html>
<body>


  <?php
    $myServer = "MyComputerName\SQLEXPRESS";
    $myUser = "Username";
    $myPass = "password";
    $myDB = "Northwind"; 

    //connection to the database
    $dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
      or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 

    //select a database to work with
    $selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
      or die("Couldn't open database $myDB"); 

    $query = "Insert into Employees values ('".$_POST["firstName"]."','".$_POST["lastName"]."')";

      mssql_query($query);

      mssql_close();

    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes it's possible, look into AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

**1. AJAX**

As tymeJV already mentioned in his comment: you can use AJAX for this.

**2. Change process.php**

A second option is to change your *process.php*-file.

```
<?php
$myServer = "MyComputerName\SQLEXPRESS";
$myUser = "Username";
$myPass = "password";
$myDB = "Northwind"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 

//select a database to work with
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
  or die("Couldn't open database $myDB"); 

$query = "Insert into Employees values ('".$_POST["firstName"]."','".$_POST["lastName"]."')";

  mssql_query($query);

  mssql_close();

  // Redirect
  header("location: index.php");
?>
```

Lose the HTML tags and add a redirect header. You do need to remove the HTML, because headers cannot be sent if there is output already...

**Why does this work?**

Headers are sent to the client's browser BEFORE any output, so before the user sees anything on screen, he gets redirected to the index.php-page.

Comment: This `header("location:index.php");` will fail. Use `header("location: index.php");` - space after colon is important.

Comment: Whoops, you're absolutely right. I was being too fast... Good call!

Comment: It's so strange, I've seen this mistake at least 15 times in the last 2 days LOL! Oh well, as long as the error is catched on time, cheers ;-)

Comment: Thanks "header("location: index.php");" worked. Thanks a lot. I wish I knew why though.  Can you explain?